# Popupwindow image link and to css file

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I put an image on a pop-up window and link it to a CSS file? Let's say I want to insert an image called `big.jpg` on my computer. Can this be done by simple Javascript code?

```
popupWindow.document.writeln('<html><head>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tressider.css" />');
popupWindow.document.writeln('</head><body>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('<h2 class="pp">'+help[3].office+'</h2>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('<p></p>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('<h3 >'+'725-0911'+'</h3>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('<p></p>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('<div class="wocao">'+help[3].Description+'</div>');
popupWindow.document.writeln('</body></html>');
popupWindow.document.bgColor="White";
popupWindow.focus();
popupWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: Where do you want to insert that image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can easily be done by adding style and img elements into the window directly.

Just use:

```
var _image = popupWindow.document.createElement('img');

_image.setAttribute('width',#);
_image.setAttribute('height',#);
_image.setAttribute('src',"myimg.png");


popupWindow.document.appendChild(_image);
```

And do the same for the style tag.

```
var _style = popupWindow.document.createElement('img');

_style.setAttribute('src',"mystyle.css");

popupWindow.document.appendChild(_style);
```

Comment: Thanks alot TootsieRoller,I will try it now

Comment: should I just put those code above the popupwindow.document.close and inside the function?

Comment: Yes, put it wherever you would want it to go in a regular web page.